# No Internet Connection on Boot with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, internet

After Doing a (cold) boot I have no internet connection.

But I actually can restore the connection with Window's Network Diagnostics:

According to the diagnostics the problem is

> "No valid IP-Configuration"

and is solved by "resetting the LAN-Connection".

However, the problem persists and I have to run the diagnostics after every boot. 
Is there a way to fix this permanently?

**EDIT**: While trying some commands I found that 'ipconfig /renew' gives a time out error:

"DHCP-Server not found"

Comment: How long do you wait before declaring 'No connection'.  I sometimes have to wait 5 minutes before I get my Internet Connection.

Comment: I have waited for more than an hour.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  I did a little more research, this article suggests changing (disabling) the firewall. http://tinyurl.com/aaw3l3k

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried what was mentioned in the article,  but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by:

*Computer -> Manage -> Device Manager -> Network Adapter -> [Your Adapter] -> Power Management -> uncheck all boxes here*

Kudos to [Viking_667](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/why-do-i-have-to-reset-my-network-adapter-local/5b7b073d-a57b-4c73-b025-3a33adb5d6f8).

Answer (score 1):

Before I gave up on Windows 8 I had this same issue with a new Samsung Chronos 7 notebook. It turned out to be a driver issue and updating driver from Samsung resolved it. Whatever was going on seemed like the WiFi was very slow in initializing with the older driver. So check to see if there is a updated driver for your NIC.